# Launch activity with NFC

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, android-applicationrecord

I'm trying to figure out how to launch a specific activity when an android device is subjected to an nfc-card with an application record in the ndef message. The activity I'm trying to launch is not the parent activity, which might be the cause of my issues...

The nfc cards are written with an ndef message containing two records, the first one is a URI record with a uri like "http://com.neodarque.nfc/item/52312321", and this is followed by an application record (created with `NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.neodarque.nfc")`)

Relevant parts from the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.neodarque.nfc.activities.LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.neodarque.nfc.activities.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:parentActivityName="com.neodarque.nfc.activities.LoginActivity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.neodarque.nfc.activities.LoginActivity" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data
            android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
            android:host="ext"
            android:pathPrefix="/com.neodarque.nfc:pkg"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I've also tried variants of the above with different android:pathPrefixes, with and without prefixing it with a slash, with and without trailing ":pkg".

And I've also tried using an intent filter for the uri-record instead, with no luck, like so:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="nfc.neodarque.com"/>
</intent-filter>
```

My app is always launched when the device gets close to my nfc cards, but it is however always my LoginActivity that is launched by that action. What am I missing?

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment that if I remove the application record from the message and only filter for the uri record everything works as intended.

Comment: The intent filter for vnd.android.nfc://ext/com.neodarque.nfc:pkg is only useful if the first record of your NDEF message is an NFC Forum external type record with the type name "com.neodarque.nfc:pkg". The other intent filter (the one for `http://nfc.neodarque.com`) should work though. Did you verify that the URI record is the **first** record within the NDEF message and that the URI starts with "`http://nfc.neodarque.com/`" (you posted a different URI above)?

Comment: Did this solve your problem?